# Python Ursina level switch

Tags: python, ursina

I'm trying to create a 2D game in ursina and I have a class `FirstLevel` in which I create the player 2D entity, enemies, cubes etc and I also use this class' `update` method for player action etc. In my main.py, first I create a menu like interface with Start & Exit buttons etc. and then if the start button is clicked I will run the first level.

My question is: can I create second class, say, `SecondLevel` (inheriting from the first some info like the player speed, enemies etc.) and destroy the `FirstLevel` class (after the first level boss is destroyed)? If not, does someone know how I can switch between different class Entities (which are levels in my case)?

The source code is here: https://github.com/VulpeanuAdrian/LordMuffinGame

```py
def start_level():
    global m
    destroy(play)
    destroy(help)
    destroy(help_text)
    destroy(exit_button)
    destroy(cat_screen)
    m = True
    m = FirstLevel()

def help_text_func():
    play.visible = True
    exit_button.visible = True
    destroy(help_text_bt)

def help_menu():
    global help_text_bt
    help_text_bt = Button(
        text=help_text_string,
        on_click=help_text_func,
        scale=(1, 0.6),
        x=-0.4, 
        y=0.35, 
        color=color.orange, 
        text_color=color.violet
    )

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = Ursina()
    window.fullscreen = True
    cat_screen = Animation('cat_gif', fps=30, loop=True, autoplay=True, scale=(13, 13))
    cat_screen.start()
    play = Button(' Play ', on_click=start_level, scale=(0.095, 0.095), x=0, y=0, color=color.blue)
    help = Button('Help', on_click=help_menu, scale=(0.095, 0.095), x=0, y=-0.1)
    help_text = Text(text=help_text_string, x=-0.3, y=0.3, visible=False, color=color.random_color())
    exit_button = Button(' Quit ', on_click=application.quit, x=0, y=-0.2, scale=(0.095, 0.095), color=color.red)
```

Answer (score 1):

There's two ways of achieving what you want, a first one which is pretty straight-forward and a second one which is more object oriented :

- One way of deleting specific entities (here from your level) is simply by storing the entities in a list, iterating through them and using `destroy(entity_name)` on each of them and then initializing the class containing the next level.
- If you prefer more OOP programming, you should make each level an `Entity` and parent to itself every `Entity` you define, making it so that you can just destroy the parent class (the level), and ursina will also destroy its children. If you want to parent an `Entity` to something else, you can just manually set a custom destroy method for the level that deletes all entities you put in it. See the example below :

```py
from ursina import *


class FirstLevel(Entity):
   def __init__(self):
       super().__init__()
       self.cube = Entity(parent=self, model='cube', texture='brick')
       self.other_cube = Entity(parent=camera.ui, model='cube', color=color.pink, scale=.1)

   def input(self, key):
       if key == 'a':
           self.unloadLevel()

   def unloadLevel(self):
       destroy(self.other_cube)
       destroy(self)



if __name__ == '__main__':
   app = Ursina()

   a = FirstLevel()

   app.run()
```

Comment: In my code i did go exactly for the  second variant , the problem is basically after i will use the destroy(self) ( in the FirstLevel class i dont know how to properly load the second level in the if__name__ == main , thanks a lot for your anwear: )

Comment: Can you be more precise about what you can't figure out ?

Comment: Sure, thanks for the reply , basically  i did try your second suggestion but after i will destroy(self) -> destroy the first level class i dont know how to start the second level class..